# ¿Es posible especificar un formato para un campo varchar en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una columna en mi base de datos que siempre comienza de la misma manera, por ejemplo digamos que siempre comienza con "ABCD" y después algún numero ¿Es posible crear un CONSTRAINT dentro de la base de datos para que no permita ingresar valores que no inicien con "ABCD"? o ¿Esto ya debo hacerlo a nivel del código de la aplicación que se conecta a la base de datos?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: En realidad no sé para que almacenas ese dato si nunca cambia... Si fuera yo no lo almacenaría y si en algún momento puede cambiar por otro valor, lo guardo aparte, a él solito, en una tabla. Cuando tengas millones de registros tendrás millones y millones de `ABCD` redundantes. No te penalizarán los ecologistas LOL, pero no me parece una buena idea tal repetición de datos.

Comment: No es que no cambie, solo que siempre comienza por los mismos caracteres después de esos caracteres es que cambia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'NoComienzaPor'
BEFORE INSERT ON 'tabla'
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF(SUBSTRING(<campo>,1,4) = "ABCD") THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "El campo debe empezar por ABCD";
  END IF
END$$
```

A cada registro que su campo no empiece por ABCD se le devolvera un error y el mensaje.

Comment: No logro hacer que funcione :c

Comment: el campo debe de llevar delante el comando NEW, quedaria NEW.<nombre_campo>

Comment: Hola Javier, al final decidí crear la condición directamente en el código de la aplicación sin embargo probare con tu solución ya que me puede ser de utilidad nuevamente en el futuro, Gracias :)